# Get background color from code-behind

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

This question may look funny, but I am struggling with the Syntax :(

I have Background color in my code behind file and need to fix the syntax here, so my Table shows correct background color:

```
<Table style="background-color:" '<%=BGColor %>' """>
```

What have i done incorrect in syntax

`BGColor` shows correct value in codebehind, during debugging.

Comment: what are you trying to do with background?

Comment: It is CMS content, so user can type any color code which will be shown as background color in preview mode.

Comment: Check results in browser. See if it is applied at all. All browsers have developer tools for such tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
<Table style="background-color:<%=BGColor %>;">
```

so finally it will look like:

```
<Table style="background-color:#cecece;">
```

or

```
<Table style="background-color:Green">
```

Please note that hex format (`cecece`) should have `#` at the beginning. And named colors (like green, yellow, white) do not need that.